# Tracking user click on item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Creating a custom user click tracking script. Need to know what is the best optimal solution to track user click without sending Ajax request to server on every click.

Don't require any code, just figuring out the optimal solution.

any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far, so that we can suggest you the optimized code

Comment: Hi @BhushanKawadkar :- I am trying to store it first locally and then send ajax request when user tries to close the browser. I know this is not the best solution, so wanted to know if there is any other way by which we send data without making ajax request on every single click. here is some sample code http://jsbin.com/monacovegi/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

I would create an array or use localStorage in javascript to store all the clicks and targets, then simply store them every so often or when the user navigates away from the page window.onbeforeunload.

Comment: That's what I am doing but window.onbeforeunload. gives a popup for leaving page, is there any other way to do this without showing user a popup

Comment: Make sure you dont have a return statement in there..
 window.onbeforeunload = function saveAllData()
            {

}

Comment: but without return it just close the browser without ajax request.

Comment: try a timeout? window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/foo',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        timeout: 4000
    });
};